# Error while connecting to the server! POST request fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I'm making a webApp with node.js, javascript and MongoDB. I wrote an ajax call that's supposed to initiate a POST request and transfer data to the server but I'm getting the error 'Error while connecting to the server!' and that's it. I'm having a hard time debugging what's wrong. :/

Here's the JS:

```
function submitDataToDB(){
    alert("HEY!");
        var URL = '/populateTables';
        var name = $('#workoutName').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: URL,
            dataType: 'html',
            data: 
            {
                'name': name,
            },
            success: function(msg) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(thrownError);
                alert('Error while connecting to the server!' + name);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's the node code if it needs any verification:

```
app.get("/dbadd", function(req,res){
    res.render('dbadd');
});

app.post("/populateTables", function(req,res){
    console.log("reached populateTables")
    res.send("YO");
})
```

Also, could someone answer the following?

1. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?
2. What's the use of passing xhr, ajaxOptions as parameters in the error part? What if I don't pass the parameters

Comment: Check the Network tab of the browser's console to see what the problem is.

Comment: `What's the use of passing xhr, ajaxOptions as parameters in the error part?` for debugging ... so you can see what they are!

Comment: The arguments to the `error:` function are `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`. Why do you have `ajaxOptions` there?

Comment: I was just using a code-template from coursework slides so that's where ajaxOptions come from. I should've looked more before using that that's my bad